# Substitution of Complex Variable in integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, substitution

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\log(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})]-\log{2}}{e^{2ix}-1}e^{ix} \,dx$$

I am wondering if a complex variable substitution the likes of $iu=e^{ix}$, $\,du=e^{ix}\,dx$ is justifiable? In my mind. when $x=0, u=0$ and when $x=\pi/2, u=1$ which would make the integral
$$-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(iu-i/u)-\log(2)}{1+u^2}\,du$$

but it is not numerically equivalent. Is it possible to introduce a complex variable substitution to solve the integral, and if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some rearranging the integral is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\log\cos x}{\sin x}dx = \frac{1}{2i}\int_0^1\frac{\log t}{1-t^2}dt$$

by the substitution $t = \cos x$. Then expand the denominator as a geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2i} \int_0^1 \log t \cdot t^{2n}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1}{2i(2n+1)^2} = \frac{i\pi^2}{16}$$

by integration by parts and then using the sum of the odd terms of the Basel problem.

Comment: I make it $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln\cos x}{2i\sin x}dx$, so you need to divide by $4i$, giving $\frac{\pi^2i}{16}$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks! I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the wrong track. I would look at
$$
\log(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})-\log2
=\log\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2\right)
=\log(\sin x)
$$
and
$$
\frac{e^{ix}}{e^{2ix}-1}
=\frac1{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}
=\frac1{2\cos x}
$$
so your integral turns into
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(\sin x)}{2\cos x}\;dx.
$$
Can you work on this?